# How to access radiobutton list value through Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using an ASP.NET RadioButton List which is bind with ObjectDatasource as given in following

Sample code:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="rdabcType" DataSourceID="roleSource"             DataTextField="ABCName" DataValueField="ABCID" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
                <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="abcSource" SelectMethod="GetABCType" runat="server">
                <asp:ObjectDataSource/>
```

I want to access "value" of radio button list in Javascript. Can anyone suggest how to do that.

Comment: I have just added sample code

Comment: When putting code into a question, make sure you have 4 spaces (spacebar presses) in front of the code on each line or it will not show up.  You can go back and edit your question to include it and then maybe someone can help you solve the problem.

Comment: Can you also show us what this renders in html to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can iterate through the collection and look for selected

```
var radioObj = document.getElementById("rdabcType");
for(radioItem in radioObj){
  if(radioObj[radioItem].selected == true){
      //TODO: Implement
      var radioValue = radioObj[radioItem].value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to iterate correctly through all the items is:

```
var types= document.getElementsByName("<%=rdabcType.UniqueID%>");
for (var j = 0; j < types.length; j++) {
    var whatYouWant = types[j].value;
}
```